# How to backup database in autocommit mode off

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I use an ODBC connection to backup a database. my code is this:

```
UPDATE [ATIDGEN] SET [LASTID] = '25' WHERE [TABLEID] = 'ATLOGIN';
//success
::SQLEndTran(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hdbc, SQL_COMMIT);
//success
BACKUP DATABASE [ArazDB2] TO DISK = 'D:\Amin88\Total\BKUP-13950621.BAK' WITH INIT,NOSKIP
//state 42000, Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.
```

If I remove the UPDATE command above, backup returns SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, and sql-server logs report this:
//BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE ArazDB2. check the backup application log for detailed message, but the backup file is created!.
1- After update, why sql-server is in a transaction? I explicitly called SQLEndTran.
2- without update, Why sql-server log reports backup failure, but the backup file is created?
Can any one help me?

Comment: Review the SQL log and backup history to know the details of the error. Can you post the details of the error?.

Comment: @M.Hassan. sql server managent studio/management/sql server logs/Current show exactly this message. The Only detail of which I know is the one returned bt SQLGetDiagRec: state 42000, Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

Comment: What is the client tool/application you use with ODBC connection

Comment: No tool or Application. I use the odbc API provided in visual studio.

Comment: So, transaction is still open, Check the state of SQLEndTran with  if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {...} to be sure that it's successful /or failed.

Comment: @M.Hassan, It's success, and I have shown this in the post. I think the odbc driver starts a transaction somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123123/discussion-between-m-hassan-and-mohamadreza-abdolahzadeh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a life Transaction.

Close all existing connections to the database using the sql script:

```
   alter database mydb  set single_user with rollback immediate
```

At the end of backup, run the script:

```
   ALTER DATABASE mydb  SET MULTI_USER
```

**Update**

SQL server issues an implicit COMMIT before and after any data definition language (DDL) statement.

BACKUP command is considered DDL and need implicit COMMIT.

As the database is in autocommit off, turn on autocommit before backup and then off after backup.

```
conn.autocommit = true
BACKUP DATABASE [ArazDB2] TO DISK = 'D:\Amin88\Total\BKUP-13950621.BAK' WITH INIT,NOSKIP
conn.autocommit = false
```

Comment: First, There is no other connection. I am debugging the application and The only connection is established by me. Second, I'm not allowed  to close existing connections user because I want to backup database while other users are connected and select, insert, update, delete data.

Comment: Please note that I use ODBC API to backup database in my application. I'm not running queries in sql server management studio

Comment: Very good idea. I turned autocommit on and executed BACKUP DATABASE, and then turning autocommit off is not successful. The error is This: Connection is busy with results for another command. What is the problem with this?

Comment: Set Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): Yes (the default = No). either by modifying the connectionString {MARS_Connection=yes} or by programming or Edit the ODBC configuration.

Comment: Thanks. but my new problem is this: for what command is the connection busy? and another problem: Why BACKUP DATABASE starts a transaction and passes error to caller? It should start transaction, do It's task(BACKUP), and then commit or role back transaction.

Comment: Use MARS to resolve busy connection. I simulated your case Using ODBC Driver 11 for SQL server 2012 API with c++ and update then backup successfully, Have a look to Transactions in ODBC  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131281(v=sql.110).aspx